# Is it possible to replicate mysql 4.0 to 5.0

Tags: mysql

Due to my hosting provider living in the past, I would like to know if it's possible to replicate a MYSQL 4.0 server to a 5.0 server.

At the moment I already have slave running 4.1 which is working OK, but I am really missing out of the features that exist in MYSQL 5.0.

If it's not possible is it possible to replicate from my slave running 4.1 to another slave running 5.0 ?

Sadly my hosting provider wont budge on the version.

Thanks

Comment: You should budge to a new hosting provider.

Comment: Yup. Bill is right. Dump the loosers.

Comment: I understand, and agree. However I am not in a position to do that just yet.

Comment: Considering that MySQL 4.1 is EOL, this is a massive black flag against your provider. There are no security updates being released for this version.

Comment: Like I said, I understand that, however I am not in a position to change providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially, cross-version replication is supported at most with one major version difference.  That is, 4.1 master to 5.0 slave is supported, but 4.0 master to 5.0 slave is not.  It's not that it can't work, it's that they don't test it, so they have no way of assuring that it works.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-compatibility.html

It's *possible* to replicate from 4.0 to 5.0, at least with limitations.  I just set up such a configuration on a Linux VM to test it, though I did not test a wide range of queries -- just a single `CREATE TABLE test.foo`.  So at least a bare minimum replication configuration works: the slave authenticates, receives binary logs, and starts executing statements.

But there are several kinds of backward compatibility problems with queries.  Some you can mitigate:

- Set [SQL_MODE='mysql40'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_mysql40) on the slave, or else some expressions with `NOT` won't act correctly.
- Don't use [character sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html).
- Avoid certain JOIN syntax, e.g. `SELECT * FROM A, B JOIN C ON C.x=A.y`, breaks on 5.0.
- Don't use [views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html), [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html), or [stored routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html).

That's not necessarily a comprehensive list, just what I think of immediately.

You should also read the upgrading manual pages to find other cases of non-backward compatibility and see if they apply to your application.  Most of these are uncommon cases, but we have no idea if any of them apply to your apps:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

You already understand that this is kind of ridiculous, to replicate MySQL circa 2003 to MySQL circa 2005, and expect that you're gaining the benefits of a more modern version.
It's like upgrading from a Model T Ford to a VW Bug, to get better comfort and fuel economy.

I know you said you can't move away from this hosting provider yet, but you have to expect a lot of inconvenience if you are unable to abandon the old MySQL 4.0 version.

Comment: +1 for setting it up and trying it. Above and beyond the call.